# rails install - ERROR ... executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) SSL_connect ... read server hello A: wrong version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I am very new to Linux (been living in MS world for many years).  I thought I'd try something different, like ruby on rails under linux.  Been trying to get a dev machine set up, and I must say, it's been quite overwhelming!  Here is what I have done so far, and my current problem that I cannot figure out:

Installed Linux Mint 15 (was this a bad choice?  the only reason I ask is all the difficulties I've had so far)

Ran the update manager and installed all updates.

Install git

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Install rbenv

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Install ruby-build as a rbenv plugin

```
git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
```

Install opensssl (the ruby install fails if I don't do this)

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Install ruby

```
rbenv install 2.0.0-p247
```

Set my ruby version

```
rbenv global 2.0.0-p247
```

Install rails

```
gem install rails
```

This fails with

```
Fetching: i18n-0.6.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.6.5
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number
```

So apparently, there's still something not quite right with the ssl lib?  Either that or I've taken a wrong step somewhere?  Please help, thanks!

Comment: I've been encountering this probably frequently in the last two days, but never before then.  I run gem install or bundle, and a gem will randomly fail to install with that message.  I rerun it, and it works, or in the case of bundle, works for a bit, that randomly fails on another gem.  I'm assuming it's a problem with the gem server that will hopefully get fixed soon.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am pretty new in linux world.

I was having exactly the same problem after following the same steps.

In my case it got solve just doing:

```
gem update --system
```

After that the rails installation gave me no prob.

Hope is just that!

Comment: This is a much better answer than the other answer provided, which suggests to reinstall ruby to get the latest version of Gem, which I assume is the problem ... it certainly fixed my issue :)

Comment: This fixed my issue when installing "berkshelf", following this tutorial:  http://vialstudios.com/guide-authoring-cookbooks.html  ... I encountered this error: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: wrong version number`

Answer (score 1):

I'm running rails 4 with ruby 2.0 on Linux Mint 15.

I did:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
sudo apt-get install git-core
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts    /rvm-installer)
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reload
rvm requirements
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
rvm install ruby-2.0
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

and it worked for me. Maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks.  Got this method to work.  Thank goodness for VirtualBox and shapshots...